# Type "System.Drawing.Bitmap, Version = 4.0.0.0"in data line 2380 cannot be located

Tags: visual-studio

In my VS 2008, for main project have this error for control/ form that inherits from mybase control.This does'nt happened on other solution.This my base control code:

```
[StrongNameIdentityPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand,
     PublicKey =
         "002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000" +
         "1000100e9b667e72b2a53cfa8283454ee87b14e48ecc93647a200fd05" +
         "aaf8713b0458fd4464aeefb54cf1fceb9b2fe77d702c56bc3e93e26b6" +
         "c63671da39386a095670e7d3572e4f65301de6a9089dfae5ffe68037d" +
         "7b0eee29c83c6acb8f6aa2c7a870167074e75cc6f723873f803a18d66" +
         "95ffd1c1298becf579ac64437580e57f6d4"
     )]
public partial class MyForm: System.Windows.Forms.Form 
{
    // Fields
    private bool closingAllForms;
    private SizeF scaleRatio = SizeF.Empty;
    private CommandManager commandManager;


    // Events
    internal event CancelEventHandler AfterFormClosing;

    protected MyForm()
    {
        if (!base.DesignMode)
        {
            ApplicationCache.Environment.StartOpenForm = Environment.TickCount;
                        }
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Any Idea ..thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball says that the problem is located in the form's .resx file.  Open it in a text editor, navigate to line 2380 and change 4.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0.  Look for additional ones.

Be careful when trying to back-port forms that were designed on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I really need your crystal ball :) thanks....My problem it's fix.but when I add new form, create normaly design and build it.The error will be show again.what the really problem?maybe about my localization and sign assembly?any resources for this...

Comment: No, that shattered it.  You'll need to talk more about what you do with VS2010.

Comment: can I discuss more seriously about problem of my aplication?